# Script not working in Safari - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, safari

I need to get text from a textbook inside of a repeater to use it in OnCommand of a button.

I have this script working fine in Chrome but not working in Safari.

```
<script>
    function getText(element) {     
        var myClass = "."+"com" + element.className;
        var corpo = $(myClass).val();
        alert(corpo); 
        __doPostBack(element.ID, corpo);                
    }
</script>
```

"alert" is working.

**I've already tried  this**

```
<script>
    function getText(element) {
        $().ready(function() { 
            __doPostBack(element.ID, $("." + "com" + element.className).val());
        });
    }
</script>
```

also tried return true and return false

(none of it makes any difference).

Any clue?

Comment: What does the browser console say? And ASP has little to nothing to do with this. The browser does not care about your server-side code, but the generated HTML only - so that is rather what you should be showing us, to make this problem easily reproducible. [mcve]

Comment: Ok I've simpified it. I was just wondering if there's a different way of doing what I want. Browser console says nothing. No errors..

Comment: First of all, what does “not working” mean? Be specific. What do you expect to happen, what happens instead, how have you verified this. And without knowing the HTML, this is still unanswerable. We can’t possibly know whether your attempted element selection matches anything or not. (But that is easy for _you_ to find out, by simply logging the size of the jQuery object to console at that point.)

Comment: Solved it in code behind. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it in code behind **

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBoxID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

inside OnCommand event of the button I did this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater.Items)
        {
            var tbx = item.FindControl("textBoxID") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
            if (tbx.CssClass == "ClassName")
            {
                ...run my code...
            }
        }
```